# Unable to create a stop generating button in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, chatgpt-api

I need some help for a chatbot project I’ve been working on. It suppose to work like ChatGPT. I want a stop generating function similar to ChatGPT where it will stop any text generating by a click of a button. But I have been having difficulties to do so.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import '../style.css';
import ChatMessages from './ChatMessage';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import { apiBaseUrl } from '../utils/constant';
import { ReactComponent as PBot } from '../assets/pbot.svg';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

export default function Chatbot() {
  const currentURL = window.location.href;
  const url = new URL(currentURL);

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const messageListRef = useRef(null);
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState('malay');
  const [sender_name, setName] = useState();
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState();
  const [topic, setTopic] = useState(' ');
  const [chapter, setChapter] = useState(' ');
  const [year, setYear] = useState();
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(url.searchParams.get('theme'));
  // const [stopGenerate, setStopGenerate] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const stopGenerateRef = useRef(false); // Use Ref to control text generation

  // const stopGenerateText = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    stopGenerateRef.current = false;
  }, [])

  const welcome = {
    english: {
      welcome: (name, subject, chapterTopic) => {
        if (!name || !year) {
          return `Oops, you're not signed in yet. Please <a href="https://app.pandai.org/app/signin" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">login</a> here first.`;
        } else if (!subject || !chapterTopic) {
          return `Sorry, I don't know what subject or topic you want to learn.`;
        }
        return `Hi ${name}. I’m PBot, your AI study helper. <br></br> I’m here to help you study ${subject}. If you have questions about ${chapterTopic}, you can ask me here.`;
      },
      chatInput: 'Ask me anything!',
    },
    malay: {
      welcome: (name, subject, chapterTopic) => {
        if (!name || !year) {
          return `Oops, awak belum log masuk lagi. Sila <a href="https://app.pandai.org/app/signin" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">log masuk</a> di sini dahulu.`;
        } else if (!subject || !chapterTopic) {
          return 'Maaf, saya tidak tahu subjek atau topik yang awak ingin pelajari.';
        }
        return `Hai ${name}. Saya PBot, pembantu belajar AI awak.  <br></br> Saya bersedia membantu awak belajar ${subject}. Jika awak ada soalan tentang ${chapterTopic}, bolehlah bertanya kepada saya di sini.`;
      },
      chatInput: 'Tanyakan apa saja!',
    },
  };

  function isJson(str) {
    try {
      JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }, 0);

    if (isJson(Cookies.get('PandaiChatHistory'))) {
      setMessages(JSON.parse(Cookies.get('PandaiChatHistory')));
    }
  }, []);

  function saveChatHistory(maxSavedChat = 10, expiry = 14) {
    const _history = [...messages].slice(-2);
    Cookies.set('PandaiChatHistory', JSON.stringify(_history), { expires: 14 });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentURL = window.location.href;
    const url = new URL(currentURL);

    const lang = url.searchParams.get('language');
    if (lang) {
      setLanguage(lang);
    }

    const name = url.searchParams.get('name');
    if (name) {
      setName(name);
    }

    const year_ = url.searchParams.get('year');
    if (year_) {
      setYear(year_);
    }

    const subj = url.searchParams.get('subject');
    if (subj) {
      setSubject(subj);
    }

    const topic_ = url.searchParams.get('topic');
    if (topic_) {
      setTopic(topic_);
    }

    const chapter_ = url.searchParams.get('chapter');
    if (chapter_) {
      setChapter(chapter_);
    }

    const theme_ = url.searchParams.get('theme');
    if (theme_) {
      const root = window.document.documentElement;

      root.classList.remove(theme);
      setTheme(theme_);
      root.classList.add(theme);

      localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
    }
  }, []);

  function autoResizeTextarea(textarea) {
    textarea.style.height = 'auto';
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }

  const handleChat = async (updatedMessages) => {

    if (stopGenerateRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    const requestBody = {
            message: updatedMessages,
            language: language,
            subject: subject,
            chapter: chapter,
            topic: topic,
            year: year,
            name: sender_name
          };
    
    // console.log(requestBody)

    let accumulatedText = "";
    fetch(apiBaseUrl +'/stream', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    })
    .then(response => {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        return new ReadableStream({
            async start(controller) {
                // let stopText = stopGenerateText.current
                while (true) {
                  // console.log(stopText)
                  const { done, value } = await reader.read();
                  if (done) {
                    break;
                  }
                  let newToken = new TextDecoder().decode(value);
                  accumulatedText += newToken;
                  controller.enqueue(newToken);
                  // stopText = stopGenerateText.current
                }
                controller.close();
                reader.releaseLock();
            }
        });
    })
    .then(stream => {
        updatedMessages = [...updatedMessages,{ text: '', sender: 'llm' }];
        setMessages(updatedMessages);
        const reader = stream.getReader();
        reader.read().then(function processText({ done, value }) {
            if (done) {
                return;
            }
            setMessages((prevMessages) => {
                let outputMessage = prevMessages[prevMessages.length - 1];
                outputMessage.text = accumulatedText;
                return [...prevMessages.slice(0, -1), outputMessage];
            });
            return reader.read().then(processText);
        });
    }).finally(saveChatHistory(messages));
};


  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    let updatedMessages = [];

    if (userInput.trim()) {
      const userInputMessage = { text: userInput, sender: 'user', type: 'widget', subject, chapter, year };
      setUserInput('');
      updatedMessages = [...messages, userInputMessage];
      setMessages(updatedMessages);

      if(!stopGenerateRef.current) {
        handleChat(updatedMessages);
      }
    }

    setLoading(false);

    setTimeout(() => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }, 0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const messageList = messageListRef.current;
    if (messageList) {
      messageList.scrollTop = messageList.scrollHeight;
    }
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <div className="chatbot-container dark:bg-[#3D3D3D]">
      <div id="chatbot" className="dark:bg-dark-chat-bg">
        <div id="conversation">
          <div ref={messageListRef} className="messagelist">
            <div style={{ marginLeft: '0', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
              <div className="py-5 float-left flex flex-row">
                <PBot />
                <div
                  className={`p-4 text-xs ml-4 font-thin rounded-[20px] border-[1px] border-solid border-[rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)] bg-grey-bot-bubble-chat text-black dark:bg-[#3D3D3D] dark:text-white dark:border-[#414141] clear-both max-w-[70%] tracking-wide`}
                  style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}
                >
                  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: welcome[language].welcome(sender_name, subject, chapter) }} />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <ChatMessages messages={messages} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="h-full flex ml-1 md:w-full md:m-auto md:mb-4 gap-0 md:gap-2 justify-center">
            <div className="grow"></div>
            <div className="flex items-center md:items-end">
              <div data-projection-id="51" style={{ opacity: 1 }}>
                <button
                  className="btn relative btn-neutral -z-0 whitespace-nowrap border-0 md:border"
                  as="button"
                  onClick={() => {
                    stopGenerateRef.current = true; // Clicking this button stops generating text
                  }}
                >
                  <div className="flex w-full gap-2 items-center justify-center">
                    <svg
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      fill="none"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      className="icon-xs"
                      height="1em"
                      width="1em"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                      <rect x="3" y="3" width="18" height="18" rx="2" ry="2"></rect>
                    </svg>
                    Stop Generating
                  </div>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form id="input-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="message-container bg-white rounded-3xl shadow">
            <textarea
              id="input-field"
              ref={inputRef}
              autoFocus={true}
              type="text"
              placeholder={welcome[language].chatInput}
              value={userInput}
              disabled={loading || !sender_name || !subject}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setUserInput(e.target.value);
                autoResizeTextarea(e.target);
              }}
              onInput={(e) => autoResizeTextarea(e.target)}
            ></textarea>
            <button type="submit" disabled={loading} className="generatebutton">
              {loading ? (
                <div className="loadingwheel">
                  <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                </div>
              ) : (
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="29" height="28" viewBox="0 0 29 28" fill="none">
                  <path
                    d="M10.5467 13.6296L7.95831 20.1006C7.60205 20.9912 8.36719 21.8882 9.2912 21.6304C11.1145 21.122 13.9692 20.2162 17.3799 18.7545C23.3589 16.192 27.6296 13.6296 27.6296 13.6296C27.6296 13.6296 23.3589 11.0672 17.3799 8.50473C13.9692 7.04303 11.1145 6.13721 9.29119 5.62873C8.36723 5.371 7.60202 6.26795 7.9583 7.15858L10.5467 13.6296Z"
                    stroke="#C2C2C2"
                    strokeWidth="1.5"
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                  />
                  <path d="M10.5469 13.6296H27.6298" stroke="#C2C2C2" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              )}
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

handleSubmit function will get the user text from the input field. Let say in this case I put in the input field “Please create an email to my manager stating I want a raise”. handleSubmit will try to get the text and invoke handleChat function.

handleChat function send request to backend (which contain GPT) and will get and generate response text.

The idea on how I’m suppose to do this is that when a stop generating button is clicked, handleChat will listen to the stop generating button clicked state and stop the generated text.

Listening to state means handleChat need to be in useEffect, but thats kinda not possible because handleChat needs to be invoke in handleSubmit to get the request text from user.

I have a limited knowledge on React.js and still learning it but if anyone here know any solution to this or any new approach to solve this problem is appreciated.